# Determining if device can vibrate - iPhone vs iPod Touch

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Developing an app that vibrates when a particular event occurs. I have a setting for turning the vibrate option ON or OFF.

I would like to be able to disable the display of the vibrate setting for devices like the iPod Touch that do not have vibrate capability. I know I can do this by determining the device model using:

```
UIDevice *thisDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    modelOfDevice = [thisDevice model];
```

I can then disable the Vibrate option depending on the modelOfDevice.. (i.e. not display it for iPod Touch). This works - but, I think it's bad form.. for example, if future iPod Touch devices do include Vibrate functionality, this solution would break.

So, the question.. How do I check to see if a device has the capability to vibrate??

Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Or, for example, the iPad -- can it vibrate?  I agree on the bad-form (vote up!)  Is there some kind of "device has capability: vibrate" API?

Answer (score 1):

If you just use AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) it vibrates where it can and does nothing where it cannot - just as the Apple documentation says, so you could skip the detection.
The [article][1] says just can do AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) to vibrate where possible or beep where not (iPod Touch still have beeping/keypress-click-sound ability)

[1]: http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-better-way-to-check-capabilities-of-ios-devices/ article

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible to check if a device is vibration capable.

But it's possible to identify device type.

```
- (NSString *)platformRawString 
{
    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    char *machine = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:machine];
    free(machine);
    return platform;
}

- (NSString *)platformNiceString {
    NSString *platform = [self platformRawString];
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"Verizon iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone 5";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"])    return @"iPhone6 Plus";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 2G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 4G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad 1";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad 3 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad 3 (4G,2)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad 3 (4G,3)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return @"Simulator";
    return platform;
}
```

Call the platformNiceString method .

```
NSString *device = [self platformNiceString];
if ([device isEqualToString: @"iPhone6 Plus"]) //do rest of the code here
```

But you'll have to identify each device manually.